# Create "Object" element in C# for Enterprise Architect Interop

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I looking around and finding no examples/documentation on how to create diagrams and, for my specific case, elements of the type "Object", in C# for Enterprise Architect.

I'm working in a addin for EA to import UserStories from another web application and export then to EA as **composite Objects**, which I can include some children Objects (directly mapped from children User Stories).

How do I do that, or where do I read how to do that?

Exploring the EA_Interop reference, I tought:

```
EA.DiagramObject d = new DiagramObject();
EA.Element e = new Element();
```

Adding Objects to a possible Objects list in the first case, and specifying the Element as Object in the second - both without success.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Enterprise Architect's object model is based around collections, and you add new objects by finding a collection and extending it. So you create a new diagram object by calling AddNew() on a diagram's DiagramObjects collection, you create a new element by calling AddNew() on (usually) a package's Elements collection, you create a new connector by calling AddNew() on the source element's Connectors collection etc.